# Should socket connection stay open and do they require admin rights?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm new to sockets and have a couple of questions on their usage in .NET. This is a consumer program so there won't be any scaling issues as the user runs the server and client.

1) Is it better to keep a socket connection open until the server is closed, or should I open a connection only when the user requests it and close it upon completion? It's not a real time game so requests would be intermittent, but are there any downsides to leaving the socket connection open?

2) Do sockets require the user to have admin rights if they're running the server? I looked around and it seemed that RAW sockets do, but I plan on using Stream or Dgram instead depending on which works best for my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're talking about a single socket then no it's not a big deal
   to leave it open. There are lots of ports available and if your
   socket is just sitting in a wait state it's going to consume a
   negligible amount of system resources.
2. TCP and UDP socket connections do not require admin rights to open.
   However, depending on the user's firewall settings a firewall
   exception may be required to allow your application to make an
   outside connection and depending on the firewall software *that* may
   or may not require admin rights.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It will be a minimal number of connections (max 3-5, but usually just 1) and they'd all connect to the same port. Although the user can choose their port number, as a default value, can my program use any available port that's listed as unofficial? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Technically you can use any port you like it's just considered rude. Especially if it's a port that's regularly associated with a type of service. But yes, any unofficial port should be fine.